# jQuery Mobile caching issue with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page that dynamically insert content from a call to MVC controller.

I tested this from my phone and then made some changes to the code, uploaded it to the server and ty to hit the page again from my phone and I see the old content. How can I clear the current cache and then prevent the future calls to the MVC from being cache.

this is how I load the content the div

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Method",
        data: null,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {



            $('#mobile-content').html(data);

            $('#mobile-content').trigger('create');
        },
        cache:false,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error in RenderQuestionForm");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a controller action from caching a returned view by using an annotation, for example:

```
// GET: /Index/
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.ListAll());
    }
```

It's also possible that the data being returned to a controller action is being cached by the data provider. I've run into this with LINQ, where a service I was accessing was caching LINQ queries by default. in that case I needed to clear the cache prior to each new query.